# Calculating length of Polyline using a loop? python

Tags: python, loops, distance

I need to calculate the length of this poly line with the following coordinates formatted this exact way:

```
coords = [[1.0, 1.0], [1.5, 2.0], [2.2, 2.4], [3.0, 3.2], [4.0, 3.6], [4.5, 3.5], [4.8, 3.2], [5.2, 2.8], [5.6, 2.0],
      [6.5, 1.2]]
```

using this distance formula  = √(2 − 1)
2 + (2 − 1)

our lab wants us to use a Loop, and be able to use the same code on other sets of coordinates. I am lost on where to start.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could work?

Define a function for the Euclidean distance:

```
import math 
def distance(x1,x2,y1,y2):
  return math.sqrt((x2-x1)**2 + (y2-y1)**2)
```

Then, another function which receives coords as input and gives back the sum of point-to-point euclidean distances

```
def compute_poly_line_lenth(coords):
  distances = []
  for i in range(len(coords)-1):
    current_line = coords[i]
    next_line = coords[i+1]
    distances.append(distance(current_line[0],next_line[0],current_line[1],next_line[1]))
  return sum(distances)
```